# How to build a Linked List using array elements?

Tags: java

Suppose I have built a Linked List class from scratch such as:

```
public class BookLink {
    private Book myBook;  (Book is another class I already have defined)
    private BookLink nextLink;

    public BookLink (Book someBook) {
        myBook = someBook;
        nextLink = null;

    public void setNextLink (Book nextBook){
        nextLink = nextBook;
}
```

And then suppose I had an array (Book[]) called myBooks. How can I elegantly loop through the array and build a Linked List from it using the aforementioned class? In other words, myBooks[0] would be set as the head, myBooks[1] would be the next link in the chain all the way up until myBooks[myBooks.length-1] being the tail?

Note: I did not list all the methods in the BookLink class that there would usually be, e.g. getNextLink or get/setMyBook. If they are necessary to answer the question, please feel free to reference the methods as if they existed. Thank you!

Comment: You should complete your linked list definition first. A complete linked list definition will set its head and add elements to it.

You can then just iterate over the list and insert elements to the list.

Comment: `nextLink` has type `BookLink`, but you're assigning `Book` to it

Comment: You really need to code your linkedlist completely before attempting the next step. I know you said that you didn't put the whole class in your question, but without it, we cannot help you further.

Comment: Um, if someone's writing a very simple linked list, this _is_ a complete implementation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman really? So how do I get back to the head of the list after adding everything to it?

Comment: @blahfunk a `BookLink` _is_ the head of a list.

Comment: You can't get to the head. It is private! There is no method defined for getting the current NODE's value even. All I can do is set the next link. I cannot traverse this list as there is no method to do so. We are assuming a whole lot about his list here...,

Answer (score 0):

Very easily:

```
BookLink current = null;
for (int i = books.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  BookLink newHead = new BookLink(books[i]);
  newHead.setNextLink(current);
  current = newHead;
}
```

Just iterate backwards and build it up from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Or Like this. Using a dummy `head` and return that `head.nextLink` when you finished may help to build the loop.

```
BookLink head = new BookLink(null);
BookLink ptr = head.

for(int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    ptr.nextLink = new BookLink(books[i]);
    ptr = ptr.nextLink;
}

return head.next;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have implemented your linked list properly, you could do it as simple as this.

```
public void insert(Book[] books) {
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        insert(books[i]);
    }
}

public void insert(Book book) {
    if (this.head == null) {
        this.head = new BookLink(book);
    } else {
        Node temp = this.head;
        while (temp.getNext() != null) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        temp.setNext(new BookLink(book));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is stuck in an endless loop? You are calling yourself?

Comment: @blahfunk Thanks to method [overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), Java realizes that there is a difference between `public void insert(Books[])` and `public void (Book)`.

Comment: Who's insert is that, then? `insert(book)` is a method for what object?

Comment: @blahfunk I tried to avoid providing the linked list insertion method (like stated in the answer), but I have edited it to include it.

Comment: I am not trying to throw rocks at you here, btw. I am just pointing out that without a good idea of how his list is setup, we are making assumptions about how his code will work. I understand he said didn't list all the methods, but without that, our solutions are confusing at best.

Comment: @blahfunk I think it is very reasonable to assume that a linked list would have some kind of insertion method. After all, the questions was not how to implement the insert.

Comment: These are methods that should be included within the class definition of BookLink?

Comment: @Isaac Only you can know which methods your class needs. Read your assignment, and read about Linked Lists and it should be obvious what you have to define.